# NullReferenceException using TextBox array

Tags: vb.net, textbox, nullreferenceexception

```
Dim NameBoxes = New TextBox(6) {Me.Controls("txt_Name1"), Me.Controls("txt_Name1"), Me.Controls("txt_Name2"), Me.Controls("txt_Name3"), Me.Controls("txt_Name4"), Me.Controls("txt_Name5"), Me.Controls("txt_Name6")}

For declarecounter As Integer = 0 To 6
   NameBoxes(declarecounter).Text = "Student" + declarecounter
Next
```

Isn't working for some reason, I have this code execute on form load. And then when I try

```
NameBoxes(1).Text = "Bob"
```

My program crashes with a NullReferenceException, even though I supposedly set the content of these textboxes to something with that for loop on form load.

Comment: I'm gonna go on a [quite stable] limb and say `Me.Controls("txt_Name1")` returns null. Remember that Controls(..)  should only accessed *after* the controls are loaded (as they may still evaluate to null, or may simply not be present yet, while the form is initializing).

Comment: Why aren't you using the textbox names directly?

Comment: @DonA Because that would be a bunch of redundant code. This is perfectly viable solution (and replacement for control arrays).

Comment: Not anymore than what your already doing and intellisense would keep you correct.

Comment: Those are the direct name of the textboxes, and these controls are already present on the form.

Comment: you CANT replace the controls collection unless you work at MicroSoft...do you mean control arrays?  Better to use a List(of T) for that vs an array

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, I corrected that.

Comment: @DonA Friend WithEvents txt_Name1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

Comment: @DonA However, you do have a valid point. It should be written as: `New TextBox(6) { txt_Name0, txt_Name1 .. }` for non-dynamic controls.

Comment: @Plutonix An array is perfectly fine, easier to instantiate, and does not affect the issue.

Comment: maybe the textboxes belong to a container so not `Me.Controls`

Comment: I removed the Me.Controls and declared the array as an above user recommended. I am still getting the same exception when I try to execute the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the initialization of this control array is done on a class level variable - then the controls have not been initialized yet(null values), place your code in the `form_load` event and see if it fixes the problem. Declaring it in calss level gives you access throughout the class, you must initialize it in the Load event - after the controls exist.

```
Public Class form1
   'class level, can't initialized here
   Dim NameBoxes() As TextBox
   Private Sub Form1_load(...) Handles Me.Load
     NameBoxes = {initialize here}
   ...
```

Comment: where class level? or load event?

Comment: Class level, the load event is where the for loop is executed.

Comment: they are not created yet at that point; the FORM doesnt even exist yet.  Inside `Sub New` is a call to InitializeComponent, THATS where the controls are created.  And the form exists once Sub New ends.

Comment: By moving the initialization to the form load event, I can't access it then throughout my program. It won't let me declare them as Public shared.

Comment: You can access it throughout the program - re-read the answer.

Comment: DECLARE it at the class level; POPULATE it in Form Load or Shown

Comment: check off his answer to accept it and gain a little rep for yourself